# Confusion about Lie algebra representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

Maybe this is silly.

Let $L$ be a Lie algebra over the field $\mathbb{F}$, recall that an $L$-module is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{F}$-vector space $V$ together with a bilinear action $L \times V \to V: (x,v) \mapsto x \circ v $ such that
\begin{equation*}
    [x,y] \circ v = x\circ(y\circ v)- y \circ (x \circ v)
\end{equation*}

All standard textbooks on Lie algebra says this defines a representation $\rho: L \to \text{Lie}(\text{End}（V))$ where $n$ is the dimension of $V$. Indeed, It is easy to verify that the map is  a Lie algebra homomorphism. However, my question is, why the definition of an $L$ module implies each element of $L$ can be identified with an $\textbf{automorphism}$ of $V$ (instead of an endomorphism)? Is it possible that the action of $L$ is not injective, i.e. , $x \circ v_1 = x \circ v_2$ where $v_1 \neq v_2$? Also, what is $\rho(0)$? If $\rho(0)$ is the identity matrix, this implies $0 \circ v = v$, which does not seem quite right.

Comment: You must be misreading something.  I cannot believe that a single standard textbook on Lie algebras says this.

Comment: For example, the result is stated in http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Max.Neunhoeffer/Teaching/liealg/liealg.pdf on page 14. Can you tell me what I am missing?

Comment: These are not automorphisms. The representation is in the matrix ring  $M_n(F)$ considered as a Lie algebra ($[x,y]=xy-yx$).There is no natural structure of a Lie algebra on $GL$.

Comment: Page 14 states no such thing; the symbol $GL_n(F)$ does not even appear anywhere on it.

Comment: Sorry I just corrected the symbol. So $\rho(x)$ is not necessarily an automorphism？

Comment: It is not necessarily an automorphism. In fact its square can be $0$.

Comment: For example for nilpotent Lie algebras, it's quite possible for not a single $\rho(x)$ to be an *auto*morphism.

Answer (score 2):

The symbol $\operatorname{Lie}(\operatorname{End}(V))$ presumably refers to the commutator Lie algebra of the endomorphism algebra of $V$.  In other words, it is the set of *all* linear endomorphisms of $V$, with the commutator operation as the Lie bracket.  So, there is no assertion here that $\rho(x)$ is always invertible.  Indeed, unless $V$ is trivial, then $\rho(x)$ will not always be an automorphism, since $\rho(0)$ must be $0$ (that's part of what it means for $\rho$ to be a Lie algebra representation, since it must in particular be linear).